# VS13 C++ unexpected integral overflow

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Consider this C++ code in VS13:

```
long long Number;
Number =  10000000000*900;
Number =     10000000*214;
Number =     10000000*215;
Number =    (long long) 10000000*215;
```

When you compile it you get `warning C4307: '*' : integral constant overflow` for line 4. When you run the code there is effectively an integral overflow. The other lines are OK. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Which of them is line 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `10000000` constant (literal) is by default treated as a `int` constant as it fits the `int` type:

> The type of the integer literal is the first type in which the value
>   can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base
>   and which integer-suffix was used

(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

Therefore the multiplication is done within `int` type (no integer promotion happens). You can consider the line

```
Number =     10000000*215;
```

as if it was

```
const int tmp1 = 10000000;
const int tmp2 = 215;
Number = tmp1*tmp2;
```

Obviously this will produce overflow, and similarly the third and the last line will not produce it. For the second line, the compiler understands that `10000000000` does not fit neither `int` neither `long`, and therefore uses `long long` for it.

You can use the `ll` suffix to force a constant to be `long long`:

```
Number =     10000000ll*215;
```

Answer (score 1):

Literal numbers are by default, understood to be of type `int`.  In Visual Studio, that's a 32-bit integer.  Multiplying two ints together results in an int.

Therefore this expression:

```
10000000*215   // (hex value is 0x80266580.)
```

is already going to be an overflowed since the expected value can't be expressed as a 32-bit positive int. The compiler will interpret it as `-2144967296`, which is completely different than `2150000000`.

Hence, for force the expression as a 64-bit, at least one of those operands has to be 64-bit.  Hence, this works nicely:

```
Number =     10000000LL * 215; // LL qualifies the literal number as a "long long"
```

It forces the whole expression (long long multiplied by int) to be treated as a long long.  Hence, no overflow.